# iostream required for inheriting from class template

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, iostream

When deriving a class from a class template (e.g. pair), it seems like we need to include iostream:

This code works:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Vector: public std::pair<double,double> {
public:
    Vector() {}
    Vector(double a, double b): std::pair<double,double> (a,b) {}
};

int main
{
    return 0;
}
```

But if we omit the `#include <iostream>` it doesn't even compile:

```
5 error: expected template-name before '<' token
```

What feature of `iostream` is required for this kind of inheritance?

Comment: I would expect you to include tuple or util to get std::pair

Comment: `std::pair` is in `utility` header. I guess `iostream` includes `utility` as well.

Comment: BTW not sure pair has a virtual destructor,  this inheritance may cause you troubles

Comment: You should generally avoir public derivation from a class like that and use composition instead. For example, that code would break encapsulation by allowing external code to modify the `pair` data members (unwanted public access to implementation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What feature of iostream is required for this kind of inheritance?

No feature. It's just that on your system `<iostream>` may be including the [`<utility>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/utility) header where `std::pair` is defined. That means you get a transitive inclusion of the correct header. Standard headers are allowed to include one another as an implementation detail, but that is not something one can portably rely on.

You should dispense with the wrong header that just so happens to work, in favor of the correct one.